# Unable to show icon on toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I tried all the solutions but still unable to show icon on toolbar, in my main project I have a toolbar and under it toolbar and inside toolbar, fragments, no matter what I tried I'm unable to show icon on toolbar, here is mainActivity.java which extends AppCompatActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_main_screen);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("Title");


    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Today"),true);
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Settings"));

    tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
}

     @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 </style>
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

tools:context="address">

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    //android:showAsAction="always" tried this as well
    android:icon="@drawable/share"/>
```

mainactivity.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
    android:elevation="3dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
     />
```

Nothing is working, not sure abou how to implement custom namespace but I changed name from app to custom but didn't work also there is enough space but still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always do this for toolbar's title and icon :

Because I don't have access to a computer right now , I cant post a complete sample but I'll describe :

First set your `toolbar` height like this : `layout_height="android:?attr/actionBarSize"` then in the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` tag put a `LinearLayout` with these attributes : `android:layout_width="match_parent` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical|left"`  then put an `ImageView` in the `LinearLayout` with these attributes:

```
width="wrap_content"
height="match_parent"
scaleType="fitXY"
adjustviewbounds="true"
src="@drawable/icon"
```

if you want to add a title just add a text view after adding the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

On your activity class you need this :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think I forgot to add in post added in question please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try to use both

```
  android:showAsAction="always"
  app:showAsAction="always"
```

Ignore the warning that you should use `app:showAsAction`

Comment: I did, you can see posted question, both together and individualy